# jQuery Accordion 'height: auto' causes animation glitch

Tags: jquery, animation, accordion

I'm using a jQuery Accordion, and I want each section to be able to resize dynamically according to the inner content. So I set the styling of .ui-accordion-content-active to 'height: auto'. This works while one particular section is active; it resizes correctly to accommodate the content inside it.

However, the height property seems to affect the animation when selecting different sections of the Accordion. It looks like it starts to slide, but the auto height takes over and both sections are fully open for a brief time, and finally the previously active one closes.

It seems like there should be a correct way to force an Accordion content div to resize dynamically, without affecting the animation. I'd appreciate any tips, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Under Script tag, write the code given below.

```
$(function() {
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "content"
  autoHeight: false
 });
});
```

:)-

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the markup from the no-auto-height demo on the jQuery UI site?
It seems to do exactly what you are asking.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height

Comment: I tried that; it works initially, but the Accordion div won't resize dynamically if the content inside it gets longer (e.g. an accordion div contains an expandable file hierarchy). I may be able to use the accordionchange event to toggle 'height: auto'.

Comment: So are you appending markup inside the accordion? Maybe you need to reinitialise the accordion after the markup has been added for it to get the correct height. Or there is a show/hide function within the accordion? In which case you may need a function to get the height of the inner content and apply it to the height of the accordion section.

Comment: Interestingly, I found that setting fillSpace to false fixes my problem. I guess fillSpace not only causes the Accordion to fill the height of its parent, but also limits it to that height. With fillSpace off, it is free to expand as new content is appended to the inner divs.